# Update complex object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state like this:

```
export interface IProfile {
    id: number,
    name: string;
    avatarUrl: string;
    events: Array<IEvents>;
    friends: Array<IProfileMini>
}

export interface IEvents {
    whoProfile: IProfileMini,
    text: string,
    posted: string
}

export interface IProfileMini {
    userId: number,
    avatar: string,
    name: string,
}


const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Partial<IProfile>>({});
```

And I want to update *only* `events` field in IProfile.

How to correctly construct `setProfile` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
setProfile({
  ...profile,
  events: `your_new_value`,
})
```

By using the spread operator, you will not mutate the old `profile`.